# Sass: print to terminal

Tags: logging, console, sass

Is there a way to have Sass print out a variable to the terminal?

Comment: Are you trying to log to the devtools in Chrome/Firefox or to the terminal when running sass?

Answer (score 108):

## Sass 3.3 and older

There are 2 error related directives:

[@debug](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_5)

> The @debug directive prints the value of a SassScript expression to the standard error output stream.

```
@debug 10em + 12em;
```

outputs:

```
Line 1 DEBUG: 22em
```

[@warn](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_6)

> The @warn directive prints the value of a SassScript expression to the standard error output stream. It's useful for libraries that need to warn users of deprecations or recovering from minor mixin usage mistakes.

```
@warn 'This is a warning';
```

## Sass 3.4 and newer

[@error](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_7)

> The @error directive throws the value of a SassScript expression as a fatal error, including a nice stack trace. It’s useful for validating arguments to mixins and functions. For example:

```
@error 'This is an error';

.foo {
  background: red;
}
```