# Is there a way to print SASS value to output?

Tags: css, sass

Suppose we have:-

`$value: 13.37;
$length: $value + 0em;`

Now i wanted to check the value of **$length**.
Is there anything similar to Javascript's Console.log?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729192/sass-print-to-terminal

Comment: `@debug` should work, isn't it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want it to appear on the page itself, I believe you could attach it as the value of a pseudo-element. Something like:

```
body::before{ content: "#{$length}"}
```

Additionally, sass includes `@error`, `@warn`, `@debug` directives that will log things to the terminal to verying degrees of of noisiness.

```
@error "the value of $length is `#{$length}`"
```

More info on those can be found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-error-warn-and-debug-directives/)