# Is there any way to output an SCSS variable directly into the compiled .css file?

Tags: css, sass

This is an enormous simplification of what I'm trying to do, but suppose I build an entire CSS declaration into an SCSS variable, like:

```
$myclass: "
  .myclass {
    display: block; }";
//Now I just want to 'echo' the string $myclass directly to the CSS
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Maybe knowing your actual use case could help users suggest better alternatives. I mean, I can't understand why you'd want to do that. You can write the CSS directly.

Comment: If you just want to see whats the value in it may be you can use @debug ..this link could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729192/sass-print-to-terminal

Comment: If you just want the value to be printed out in the compiled css, I recommend simply using a `mixin`

Comment: You could output it inside of a CSS comment, but guessing that’s not what you want. http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/f7b90b3365ade24f1c26ce95956860a9